# JavaScriptCore and JSExport strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, ios

I am using Xcode 8, Swift 3, and iOS 10 and trying to use JavaScriptCore and JSExport to pass data between my iOS app and some javascript code. I am getting some strange results. For example, the following code inside an iOS Playground gives me unexpected output.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import JavaScriptCore

@objc protocol TestJSExports: JSExport {
    static func test() -> TestJSExports
}

class Test : NSObject, TestJSExports {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("Constructor called")
    }

    class func test() -> TestJSExports {
        return Test()
    }
}

print("Starting")
let javascriptContext = JSContext()
javascriptContext?.setObject(Test.self, forKeyedSubscript: "Test" as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)!)
let result = javascriptContext?.evaluateScript("Test.test();")
print(result ?? "nil")
```

I expect

`Starting
Constructor called`

Instead I get

`Starting
undefined`

Does anyone know why this might occur?

Comment: javascriptContext? why you added question mark to it?

Comment: It's called an optional. It's part of the Swift language.